# SonarQube Scan multiple C# project (sonar.inclusions issue)

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using SonarQube Community Edition Version 8.9.10 and Sonar Scanner for MSBuild (5.13.0.66756-net5.0)

I have a folder containing multiple C# projects with a single .sln file, which usually takes around 12 seconds for compiling (after dotnet clean).

When using sonarqube, I am encountering very slow performance (over 1 minute just for the build),since it seems that every project is scanned even though it has no changes.
In order to manage this, I am trying to use sonar.inclusions to filter out which files to scan. However, by looking at the log during the build phase, it seems that every project is again checked for issues, consuming a lot of time. Also, it seems like everything gets recompiled unline when building normally.

For example, this row is in the build output:
Sonar: (monocromo.example.API.slmp.csproj) Project processed successfully

However, the sonar.inclusions path given does not include the path monocromo.example.API.slmp.csproj. Why does it need to scan it then?
Is there any way to speed up the scanning process in my situation?
Thank you a lot

### UPDATE:

As asked, I will now explain the details about how I perform the scan. At the beginning, I tried using sonar-scanner as I do for Java, but an error message told me to install MSBuild. Now, in order to run a scan on a project, I do the following:

```
dotnet sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.13.0.66756-net5.0/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"project_key" /d:sonar.token="token" /v:1

dotnet build solution.sln

dotnet sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.13.0.66756-net5.0/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end /d:sonar.token="token"
```

Comment: Can you please share a (redacted version) of your SonarQube build task? Also I'm wondering why you mention `dotnet clean` but are using MSBuild for the scan. This sounds like you are building everything twice. I'm using SonarCloud so there might be something different when using SonarQube.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am used to scan Java projects, and it is really simple since no compiling is required. However, by running sonar-scanner as usuale, an error message states that I should do the hole process with MSBuild, which is what I now am trying to do. However, I use it by doing something like `dotnet SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin ... ` but I don't really remember where I got this from. This consists in running three commands in the command line, so there is no real build task. Sadly, I cannot switch to sonarcloud but have to stick with this version for now.

Comment: Ok, this looks familiar enough. Maybe it's just a matter of aligning your target platform with the Sonar scanner flavor to solve the initial error you got. For my project, I also experienced a lot of trouble with project dependencies and MSBuild needs some tweaking to address that. What's your projects target platform?

Comment: Each project of the folder has TargetFramework net6.0

Comment: As a first-off you could try decorating your .csproj file with the `<SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>` as described in [Excluding projects from analysis](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/#excluding-projects). Also instead of `sonar.inclusions` I'd rather rely on `sonar.exclusions` if you build a complete `.sln`.

Comment: It seems like `<SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>` is the only way to fully prevent the project also from recompiling. Thank you!